# How to change android to silent mode with a button click?

Tags: android

This is my java code

```
 Button b1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    vibrator = (Vibrator) getSystemService(VIBRATOR_SERVICE);

    b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            vibrator.vibrate(1000);
            getApplicationContext();
            AudioManager audioManager = (AudioManager) getSystemService(AUDIO_SERVICE);
            audioManager.setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_SILENT);
        }
    });
```

and this is my xml code

```
    <Button
    android:layout_width="117dp"
    android:layout_height="71dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="144dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="372dp"
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:text="button"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" />
```

I just want to change the device state to silent mode on the button click. I tried but its not working and app starts to crash when the button is clicked

Answer (score 0):

Add below in Manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NOTIFICATION_POLICY" />
```

Set directly or Request for Runtime Permission for API 23 and above:

```
private void requestMutePermissions() {
    try {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 23) {
            AudioManager audioManager = (AudioManager)getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
            audioManager.setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_SILENT);
        } else if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23) {
            this.requestForDoNotDisturbPermissionOrSetDoNotDisturbForApi23AndUp();
        }
    } catch (SecurityException e) {

    }
}
```

..

```
private void requestForDoNotDisturbPermissionOrSetDoNotDisturbForApi23AndUp() {

    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    // if user granted access else ask for permission
    if (notificationManager.isNotificationPolicyAccessGranted()) {
        AudioManager audioManager = (AudioManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
        audioManager.setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_SILENT);
    } else{
        // Open Setting screen to ask for permisssion
        Intent intent = new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_NOTIFICATION_POLICY_ACCESS_SETTINGS);
        startActivityForResult(intent, ON_DO_NOT_DISTURB_CALLBACK_CODE);
    }
}
```

Activity Result:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    // Check which request we're responding to
    if (requestCode == ON_DO_NOT_DISTURB_CALLBACK_CODE ) {
        this.requestForDoNotDisturbPermissionOrSetDoNotDisturbForApi23AndUp();
    }
}
```

Comment: First code block in your answer: just `else` is perfectly sufficient. There's no benefit from having `if ... else if...` where `else if` covers the same case plain `else` would. Also I suggest you stop using `23` and put `Build.VERSION_CODES.M` instead, for increased readability.